# sort a JavaRDD using sortBy

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have a `JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Integer>>` and want to sort it based on its Integer field.

If RDD has only one field, it works correctly.

```
JavaRDD<Integer> sorted = wordSet.sortBy(x -> x, false, 10);
```

But as its fields are Tuple2, it doesn't work.

I tried the following code:

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Integer>> sorted1 = wordSet1.sortBy(new Function<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Integer>() {
        public Integer call(Tuple2<String, Integer> value) throws Exception {
            return value._2;
        }
    }, false, 10);
```

Also I tried using `Comparator` but it doesn't work too.

```
public class TupleComparator implements Comparator<Tuple2<String, Integer>>, Serializable
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Tuple2<String, Integer> o1, Tuple2<String, Integer> o2) {
        return o1._2() < o2._2() ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE: A complete and verifiable example:**

```
public class sortRDD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("sort");
        JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }
        JavaRDD<Integer> numberRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(numbers);
        System.out.println(numberRDD.collect());
        JavaRDD<Integer> sorted = numberRDD.sortBy(x -> x, false, 1);
        System.out.println("sorted:");
        System.out.println(sorted.collect());

        //RDD of tuples
        List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> words = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, Integer>>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            words.add(new Tuple2<String, Integer>("word" + i, i));
        }
        JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Integer>> wordSet = sparkContext.parallelize(words);
        System.out.println(wordSet.collect());
        JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Integer>> sorted1 = wordSet.sortBy(new Function<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Integer>() {
            public Integer call(Tuple2<String, Integer> value) throws Exception {
                return value._2;
            }
        }, false, 1);
        System.out.println("sorted:");
        System.out.println(sorted1.collect());

        //Using Comparator
        JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Integer>> sorted2 = wordSet.sortBy(new TupleComparator(), false, 1);
        System.out.println("sorted:");
        System.out.println(sorted1.collect());
    }
}
```

Comment: _it doesn't work too_ doesn't tell us anything. Please provide a [mcve]!

Comment: Updated! Please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the JavaRDD to JavaPairRdd and then using sortByKey, I could get the sorted results.